# Vim: why does Ctrl+O jump to the previous file, instead of to the previous directory view?

Tags: vim

Steps to reproduce (all in the same window):

1. Edit `some-dir/file-1`
2. Run `:Ex` to see `some-dir`
3. Open `some-dir/file-2`
4. Press `Ctrl+O`

I'm sent to `some-dir/file-1`, instead of to `some-dir`.

I know I can use `:Rex`, but that's less convenient. Is there something I can add to my `.vimrc` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
:Rex
```

is the way to go.

That said, `<C-o>` works as you want, here. I'm not sure why it doesn't for you. Netrw may purposely hide itself from the jumplist but I don't remember an option that governs that behavior. Read `:h netrw` just in case.

You could create your own mapping, of course, to work around what looks a lot like a bug or possibly a mapping overlap but that doesn't really sound right to me.

What is the output of `:verbose map <C-o>`?

Comment: Output is "No mapping found". I'm using Vim 7.4 on OS X (installed via Homebrew)

Comment: Try without your `~/.vimrc`: `$ vim -u NONE`

Comment: If I do that, netrw is disabled altogether. However, if I run `/usr/bin/vim` (i.e. the native Vim 7.3), `<C-o>` works as expected (although the cursor is set to the last file).